# How does this collection sorting works in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, quicksort

I found this code on [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-numbers-arrange-the-numbers-to-form-the-biggest-number/). Nothing has to do with it. I am just trying to understand how the following sort function works with the following custom comparator.

Here is the code snippet

```
static void printLargest(List<String> arr){

    Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(String X, String Y) {
            String XY=X + Y;
            String YX=Y + X;
            return XY.compareTo(YX) > 0 ? -1:1;
        }
    });

    Iterator it = arr.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
        System.out.print(it.next());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   List<String> sample = new ArrayList<>();
   sample.add("34");
   sample.add("30");
   sample.add("9");
   sample.add("5");
   sample.add("3");

   printLargest(sample);
}
```

If I remember correctly. Java `Collection`
uses `Quick Sort` for sorting the inputs.

Here are the debugger steps:

1. `X = 30, Y = 34 , XY = 3034 , YX = 3430, return 1`
2. `X = 9, Y = 30,   XY = 930, YX = 309, return -1`
3. `X = 9, Y = 30,   XY = 930, YX = 309, return -1`
4. `X= 9, Y = 34,    XY = 934, YX = 349, return -1`
5. `X = 5, Y = 34,   XY = 534, YX = 345, return -1`
6. `X = 9, Y = 5,    XY = 59,  YX = 95,  return 1,`
7. `X = 3, Y = 34,   XY = 334, YX = 343, return 1,`
8. `X = 3, Y= 30 ,   XY = 330, YX = 303, return -1`

And the output is `9534330`. Basically the list modified itself to `9, 5, 34, 3, 30`. If I see the pattern, I am not able to figure out how they are applying `Quick Sort` here on the comparator. I need some insight here to understand the code.

Any hint would be appreciable.

## Edit 1:

If anybody missed the link of Questions. Here it's is with the working solution:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-numbers-arrange-the-numbers-to-form-the-biggest-number/. (Checkout the java solution)

Comment: The only difference here is that the "sort function" is defined explicitly instead of just the standard one which is I guess `.equals` when comparing strings. Basically `new Comparator<String>(){...}` is the sort function. You still do quick sort but compare with this defined function.

Comment: `9, 5, 34, 3, 30`, for me, doesn't look like sorted. Or maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: @MohammadZeineldeen Agreed but I still don't understand how is it working after checking the debugger

Comment: @KunLun Exactly this not even sorted but as `GeeksForGeeks` and other competitive website says that it's sorted in some way after applying the above comparator

Comment: Can you send the link? I don't understand the context in which this code is mentioned in quick sort.

Comment: @boobalan Just pasted above 

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-numbers-arrange-the-numbers-to-form-the-biggest-number/

Comment: Collection does not use Quicksort. But that doesn’t matter anyway. The comparator is broken. A comparator must return zero when the two elements are equal, which this comparator doesn’t. So if the code has the desired result, it’s just coincidence. There is no guaranty that it will have the same outcome in a different runtime environment. It’s not even clear why this code does this incorrect thing instead of just `return YX.compareTo(XY);`

Answer (score 1):

This is not sorting the individual numbers from largest to smallest.

But, this sorts the given list in an order such that when the final list of numbers is appended, will give the largest possible number that can be made by appending input numbers.

To get the maximum number, a number(`X`) in the list will have to appear before another number(`Y`) in the list, if the number(`X appended with Y`, that is, `XY = X + Y`) is greater than the number (`Y appended with X`, that is, `YX = Y + X`). Since `XY` and `YX` are of the same length the comparison of number `XY` and `YX` can be string comparison itself. This is what

```
new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String X, String Y) {
        String XY=X + Y;
        String YX=Y + X;
        return XY.compareTo(YX) > 0 ? -1:1;
    }
});
```

achieves.

In your observation,

```
X = 30, Y = 34 , XY = 3034 , YX = 3430, return 1  --> this places 34 before 30
```

because any possibility **34***30** will be greater than **30***34** provided we fix the other numbers.

```
X = 9, Y = 30,   XY = 930, YX = 309, return -1  --> this places 9 before 30
```

because any possibility **9***30** will be greater than **30***9** provided we fix the other numbers.

We can stretch this argument to other observations too.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, It's giving some ideas about how it works. One thing Why it didn't compare `"3"` with `"5"` and `"9"`. (7th and 8th point in the debugger) ? I understood that `5>9>34>30` due to comparator logi